# Vendor Files are missing

Tags: laravel, vendor

I need to reload all the vendor files.How do I install vendor using composer?
I am installing a package from GitHub which is missing vendor files https://github.com/jacurtis/Packt-Laravel-Socialite

Answer (score 5):

you need to run `composer install`, it will the check composer.json file in your project and install all the required dependencies, make sure to run the command inside your laravel project